# PyCharm says there is no errors here, but when i run the code i get ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python-3.x

```
enter code here

pizzas = ("4 seasons", "Neapolitan", "Pepperoni")

def display_pizzas(types):
    types = list(types)
    print(f"---PIZZAS({len(types)})---")
    for p, x in types, range(0,len(types)):
        print(f"{x}. Pizza {p}")

display_pizzas(pizzas)
```

im trying this weird syntax, PyCharm sees no errors here, but i get
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "...\main.py", line 9, in 
display_pizzas(pizzas)
File "...\main.py", line 6, in display_pizzas
for p, x in rodzaje, range(0,len(rodzaje)):
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm, i already found the solution whitch is:

```
enter code here

pizzas = ("4 seasons", "Neapolitan", "Pepperoni")

def display_pizzas(types):
    types = list(types)
    print(f"---PIZZAS({len(types)})---")
    for p, x in zip(types, range(0,len(types))):
        print(f"{x}. Pizza {p}")
```

bye

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your new code works but it's not compiled in a pythonic way. 
so I made a little refactor into your code.

- you don't need to convert tuple `types` to the list because the tuple is already iterable you can use for loop without converting to list
- instead of `zip` function you can user builtin `enumerate`

this is the whole code

```py
from typing import Iterable

pizzas = ("4 seasons", "Neapolitan", "Pepperoni")
# refactoring Code
def display_pizzas(types: Iterable[str] = None):
    print(f"---PIZZAS({len(types)})---")
    for counter, pizza in enumerate(types):
        print(f"{counter}. Pizza {pizza}")
    
display_pizzas(pizzas)
```